# Jasmine createSpyObj service not registering calls

Tags: angular, service, jasmine

After reading what feels like every single post about Jasmine spies not registering calls, here's my code with that exact problem:

```
describe( 'shared.FormAutocompleteComponent', () => {
    let component: FormAutocompleteComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormAutocompleteComponent>;
    let displayCtrl: FormControl;

    const mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj( 'dynSearchService', ['search', 'lookup'] );
    mockService.lookup.and.returnValue( of( { unlocode: 'ZRH/CH', name: 'Zürich' } ) );
    mockService.search.and.returnValue( of( [{ unlocode: 'ZRH/CH', name: 'Zürich' }] ) );

    beforeEach( async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
            declarations: [FormAutocompleteComponent],
            providers: [{ provide: DynamicSearchService, useValue: mockService }],
            imports: [
                NoopAnimationsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes( [] ),
                MatInputModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatIconModule
            ]
        } )
            .compileComponents();
    } ) );

    beforeEach(() => {
        displayCtrl = new FormControl();
        const group = new FormGroup( {} );
        group.addControl( 'foobar', displayCtrl );

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent( FormAutocompleteComponent );
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.config = {
            name: 'foobar',
            formControl: 'text',
            label: 'My foobar',
            lookupApi: 'location',
            searchApi: 'locations'
        };
        component.group = group;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    } );

    it( 'should create', () => {
        expect( component ).toBeTruthy();
    } );

    fit( 'should correctly extend single term to wildcard', async(() => {
        // arrange
        displayCtrl.setValue( 'zrh' );
        fixture.detectChanges();
        // act
        component.search();
        // assert
        expect( mockService.search ).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect( mockService.search ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( 'zrh*', 'locations' );
    } ) );
} );
```

The DynamicSearchService is injected into the FormAutocompleteComponent, and placing a console.log directly before the component calls DynamicSearchService#search shows that the method is clearly being called. Another console.log shows that the results returned match those for the train Jasmine spy.

```
3396 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket rlx5hC9uWlNSUz0pAAAA with id 73910165
LOG: 'callDynSearchService with displayCtrl.value=zrh'
LOG: 'callDynSearchService with displayCtrl.value=zrh'
LOG: 'About to run <search> on service with term zr* '
LOG: 'About to run <search> on service with term zr* '
LOG: 'Got results: [{"unlocode":"ZRH/CH","name":"Zürich"}]'
LOG: 'Got results: [{"unlocode":"ZRH/CH","name":"Zürich"}]'
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10 0.0.0) shared.FormAutocompleteComponent should correctly extend single term to wildcard FAILED
        Expected spy dynSearchService.search to have been called.
            at <Jasmine>
```

Running a test with

```
const srv = fixture.debugElement.injector.get( DynamicSearchService );
expect( mockService ).toEqual( srv );
```

succeeds, the only cause left seems to be that the .search() call is never recorded on the spy. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT, 06/23/2018**

Changing to defining a non-spy mockService (still injected 'useValue'), and then

```
fit( 'should correctly extend single term to wildcard', async(() => {
    // arrange
    let injectedService = TestBed.get( DynamicSearchService );
    spyOn( injectedService, 'search' ).and.callThrough();
    spyOn( injectedService, 'lookup' ).and.callThrough();
    displayCtrl.setValue( 'zrh' );
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // act
    component.search();
    // assert
    expect( injectedService.search ).toHaveBeenCalled();
} ) );
```

debugging now shows that the service in the component is the same object as 'injectedService'. The proxy changes done by spyOn also show on the components service. However, Jasmine still records 'search' to never have been called.

Comment: Some further debugging shows that the 'mockService' in the test is *not* the same object as the DI object in the component (using a simple 'ref' counter on mockService, and incrementing that later in the test. the 'ref' counter on the component stays 0).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the cause was a debounceTime() call on an Observable, some console.log statements showed that despite async() and fixture.whenStable(), the search was only executed *after* the expect() assertion ran.

The issue was eventually resolved by switching to fakeAsync and using tick().